# FileLoader in three.js gives ReferenceError: Request is not defined while unit testing using mocha

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, three.js, mocha.js, react-testing

I am trying to write a unit test for my three js utility functions.
My Project uses CRA w TS, and mocha & chai w TS for unit testing.

**GeometryUtils.spec.ts**

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import { Scene, Vector3 } from 'three';![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdU7b.png)
import { extractBoundaryOf } from './GeometryUtils';
import fs from 'fs';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTF, GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

describe('GeometryUtils.extractBoundaryOf', function () {
    it('should return a Vector3[][]', function () {
        THREE.Cache.enabled = true;
        const surfaceName = 'wall_0';
        const surfaceNormal = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        new GLTFLoader().parse(
            fs.readFileSync('./src/services/threejs/test/room_camera_geometry.gltf').toString(),
            './src/services/threejs/test/',
            function (gltf) {
                const scene = gltf.scene as unknown as Scene;
                console.log('GLTF ', gltf);
                console.log('Scene ', gltf.scenes);
                const boundary = extractBoundaryOf(surfaceName, surfaceNormal, scene);
                expect(boundary).to.be.an('array');
            },
            function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            },
        );
    });
});
```

**GeometryUtil.ts**

```js
import {
    Box2,
    BufferGeometry,
    Group,
    LineSegments,
    Mesh,
    Object3D,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Raycaster,
    LineBasicMaterial,
    Scene,
    Triangle,
    Vector2,
    Vector3,
    Line,
} from 'three';
export function extractBoundaryOf(surfaceName: string, surfaceNormal: Vector3, inScene: Scene): Vector3[][] {
    // just an example
    let allVertices: Vector3[][] = [[new Vector3(0, 0, 1)]];
    return allVertices;
}
```

Error I'm facing:

```sh
yarn run v1.22.17
$ mocha src/**/*.spec.ts
(node:34713) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)


  GeometryUtils.extractBoundaryOf
    ✔ should return a Vector3[][]
ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    at FileLoader.load (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:39258:15)
    at file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2640:11
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFParser.loadBuffer (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2638:10)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2541:24)
    at GLTFParser.loadBufferView (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2659:15)
    at file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2535:40
    at GLTFParser._invokeOne (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2468:19)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2533:24)
    at GLTFParser.loadAccessor (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2694:34)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2529:24)
    at assignAttributeAccessor (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:4206:17)
    at addPrimitiveAttributes (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:4222:17)
    at GLTFParser.loadGeometries (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3334:24)
    at GLTFParser.loadMesh (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3377:24)
    at file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2523:34
    at GLTFParser._invokeOne (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2468:19)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2521:24)
    at GLTFParser.createNodeMesh (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3739:17)
    at file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3788:38
    at GLTFParser._invokeOne (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2468:19)
    at file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3786:31
    at GLTFParser.loadNode (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3820:4)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2517:24)
    at buildNodeHierarchy (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3985:16)
    at GLTFParser.loadScene (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:3933:18)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2513:24)
    at file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2601:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFParser.getDependencies (file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2599:37)
    at file:///home/subhankar/workspace/trisetra/trisetra-decor/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:2314:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)


  1 passing (64ms)

Done in 14.62s.
```

package.json:

```json
{
   "type": "module",
   "scripts": {
      ....
      "test": "mocha src/**/*.spec.ts",
      ....,
   }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [ "node", "mocha", "chai", "lodash"],
    "typeRoots": ["typings", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

.mocharc.json

```json
{
    "node-option": [
        "experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
        "loader=ts-node/esm"
    ]
}
```

I wanna pass the GLTF object to my testing
This is my directory structure:

I tried to compile using commonjs too. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Request is a DOM API, maybe you are using Three.js outside browser environment, which cannot provide DOM API?

Comment: Hmm this could be the case. What do you suggest me to do to solve this?

Comment: Polyfill may do the work, but use it carefully because there will be side effects... In my last project, which is a "pure" node.js script, `node-fetch` and `jsdom` packages were imported for polyfill. @subhankar-pal